# Uploading files to google cloud datalab VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I have an open google cloud datalab notebook, and I'm looking at folder contents. There is an upload button, and I can use it to upload files. It works fine for any files under about 500kb, but the moment I try to upload anything larger, it simply hangs forever. I'm not trying to upload massive files via a web interface, just 10mb or less worth of data, but it still won't go through.

Does datalab have a maximum file size that you can use the web uploader for?

Answer (score 7):

Since Google Cloud Datalab Notebook is running as a docker container within the provisioned Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance, we will need to copy the file into the container itself.

1/ Copying the large file from local to GCS bucket:

```
[Local machine prompt] gsutil cp <my_file> gs://<my_bucket>
```

2/ SSH into the Datalab GCE instance from Cloud Shell:

```
[Cloud Shell prompt] gcloud compute ssh <instance name>
```

3/ Find the id of the Cloud Datalab container:

```
[GCE Instance prompt] docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND
0aa745853b54        gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:latest         "/datalab/run.sh"
```

4/ Exec into the container with the id just found:

```
[GCE instance prompt] docker exec -it 0aa745853b54 /bin/sh
```

5/ In the container's new prompt, copy the file into the notebook location:

```
[Container prompt] gsutil cp gs://<my_bucket>/<my_file> /content/datalab
```

6/ Confirm the file is copied:

```
[Container prompt] ls -l /content/datalab
```

7/ Exit the container by holding Ctrl + p + q

The my_file should also be visible from the Web GUI of Notebook.

Answer (score 1):

There's [an outstanding issue](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1324) on the Github repo for Datalab that discusses this, it's something that Datalab inherits from Jupyter 4, on which it's based, and there's unfortunately currently no way around it.